# Starting greenplum on a replicated system

Tags: database-administration, greenplum

We have recently tried to make a gold-build/replica of the server where greenplum was installed and we now installed the image on another server to see if we can start greenplum without installing it from start. But when we execute **gpstart** command, it shows the hostname of the previous server whose image was taken. I want to start greenplum on new server where image is installed but with it's own hostname. Where do I need to make changes?

Answer (score 3):

Your current cluster not only has the hostnames in gp_segment_configuration, but all of the pg_hba.conf files have ip addresses of the hosts. Your new cluster will have different ip addresses so even if you change the hostnames in gp_segment_configuration, the pg_hba.conf files will have to be updated too.

The best way to handle this is to initialize the database with HBA_HOSTNAMES=1 in the input configuration file so that the pg_hba.conf files have hostnames rather than ip addresses. On your new cluster, you have to also use the same hostnames as the other cluster.

The typical naming convention is:
mdw = master
smdw = standby master
sdw[n] = segment host

This is exactly how we built the AWS, Azure, and GCP Marketplace products too. They all use standardized names and the pg_hba.conf files have hostnames. This enables snapshots to be taken of one cluster and easily restored to another.